# how can i convert pem public key to rsa public key with bouncycastle in c#?

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle, public-key, pem

i have a pem **public** key and i want to convert to xml format public key or AsymmetricKeyParameter.

i can convert pem **Private** key to **Public/Private** xml format or asymmetricKeyParameter with PemReader in bouncyCastle in C#.but when use Pem **Public** Key in PemReader , i receive error.

please help me.
what else solution for my problem?

Comment: anybody know about this problem?

Comment: have you try to use openssl to do the conversion?

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you were looking for using BouncyCastle.

Dependencies:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
```

The code to convert from PEM to RSA XML format:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("yourPrivateKey.pem");
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(reader);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemReader.ReadObject();
AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = keyPair.Private;
RSA rsa = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters) privateKey);
string xmlRsa = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
Console.WriteLine(xmlRsa);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this entry [from Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/clr/thread/30f6bc31-bd63-4ef9-9cdd-574427913819) browse down to Bell_Wang reply, it points to some code that makes that conversion for you ([code is here](http://csslab.s3.amazonaws.com/csslabs/Siva/opensslkey.cs))